# Who is the winner

Tags: rules

[image]

My question is: who has a winning hand in this case?

Comment: Use the link above to understand the rules for deciding the winning hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Both players tie and should split the pot. They have the same poker hand as each other:

```
KK77A
```

When in doubt, just remember that poker hands are always five cards.